# Deployment group's ECS service must be configured for a CODE_DEPLOY deployment controller

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

I've encountered following error when I'm trying to create Deployment Group for ECS Cluster in Code Deploy. I've created IAM that based on CodeDeploy ECS and its policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecs:DescribeServices",
                "ecs:CreateTaskSet",
                "ecs:UpdateServicePrimaryTaskSet",
                "ecs:DeleteTaskSet",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeRules",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyRule",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "sns:Publish",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectMetadata",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": [
                        "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please let me know when I made mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 20):

If you are using **CodeDeploy**, your **ECS** service has to be defined so that
it uses **Blue/Green** code deployments rather than **Rolling Updates**:

[image: snapshot of AWS Management Console > ECS > Create Service]

HTH!

Comment: I have created my ecs service using cloudformation template. There is no property in cloudformation to specify to use Blue/Green Deployment model. I am following a thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304700/required-cloudformation-script-for-blue-green-deployment-on-ecs which says support for this hasn't been added in cloudformation yet.

Answer (score 11):

Also if you are using terraform you can simply fix it by add this to `aws_ecs_service`:

```
  deployment_controller {
      type = "CODE_DEPLOY"
  }
```

Comment: how to do this from console ?